# I can't run the windchill test system

Tags: java, ptc-windchill

While I was trying to load the new classes I wanted to create in windchill shell, my necessary files in windchill were deleted during the installation. All classes in the file are deleted when adding a new package with windchill shelland the test system stopped working.  What can I do for it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If classes were deleted because source files didn't exist then you need to restore them from backup or a different system with the same version. Try to not compile the full `com` package, but compile just your custom one. It won't delete other classes.